# Is there any way to change the font of multiple VSE text strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, text-object

Like the question says. I have a video with a few dozen text strips. If I want to change the font, it appears that I have to do it one at a time. "Copy to Selected" is greyed out when I try it.

Comment: I would try to write a python script for this

Comment: It is not possible to do this in Blender as it is, but this subtitle import add-on has the copy to selected function for fonts: https://github.com/tin2tin/import_subtitles